# String compare, system call read

Tags: c

I was trying to read in from stdin and print the input to a file, if the input is quit then I want to stop the program. However, this does not seem to work, the if clause if not activated when i type "quit". What is wrong with this code?

```
while( (n_char = read(0, (void *)buffer, 10)) != 0){
    if (strcmp(buffer, "quit") == 0){
        printf("equal\n");
        exit(0);
    }
//Display the characters read
    n_char = write(inFile, buffer,n_char);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) doesn't add the null byte termination to `buffer`. But `strcmp()` expects its arguments to be terminated with null byte.

Add the null byte before `strcmp()`:

```
buffer[n_char] = 0;
```

(If `n_char` is 10 then you need to be sure `buffer[n_char]` doesn't result in out of bound access i.e. have at least one extra byte in `buffer` for the null termination. On the other hand, you could use strncmp()`).

Also, your condition is wrong. `read()` can retun -1 on error which would pass your condition. Change it to:

```
while( (n_char = read(0, buffer, 10)) > 0) {
```

Notice that I removed the unnessary cast to `void *`.

Comment: You should only use the `str*` functions on C-style strings. The documentation for each of these functions makes clear that their inputs must be strings, not arbitrary chunks of data read from a file or network connection.

Comment: @InnoveerHipstirt Check id there's a newline in the input read.

Comment: Hey thanks I forgot that. Now i can make it work. Also strncmp works!

Comment: actually it should have been buffer[n_char-1] = 0;

Comment: @InnoveerHipstirt That's true only if the buffer happens to contains a newine (and you want to remove) -- which seems to the case with you input. In general if read() reads N bytes then you'd want to insert null byte at the Nth index in order to use it as a C-string. Take an example: if `read()` returns `abc` then N will be 3 and buffer[3] is where the null terminator would go.